# C# Vlc.DotNet Libraries - Null reference exception on setmedia

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, libvlc

I'm aware some partial answers have been offered, both on SO and most closely here:https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/issues/217

I want to make a dynamic vlc player in my winform.
I have succesfully added a player statically:

```
        vlcControl2.SetMedia(new System.IO.FileInfo(file1));
        vlcControl2.Play();
```

But when I try and create a dynamic one, I get a null ref exception on the setmedia line:

```
var new_vlc = new VlcControl();
        new_vlc.Enabled = true;
        new_vlc.VlcLibDirectoryNeeded += checkdir2;
        new_vlc.Height = 300;
        new_vlc.Width = 300;
        new_vlc.SetMedia(new System.IO.FileInfo(file2));
```

I get that the new_vlc is somehow null, but cannot find what it is I haven't set, and I've been at this for hours.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Looking at the source code, SetMedia uses `myVlcMediaPlayer` which is only ever assigned after calling `EndInit()`, but those lines are, for some reason, commented out. Try to call `new_vlc.EndInit();` before `SetMedia()`

Comment: Thank you, this worked!

Answer (score 1):

As Camilo pointed out, if you are allocating a new WinForms control yourself, you are responsible for calling BeginInit/EndInit manually (granted, BeginInit does not do anything special, but it's how you're supposed to use `ISupportInitialize`).

We should probably throw a better message than the NullReferenceException you're having.